# I am unable to access my website hosted in firebase Hosting from India

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I am unable to access my website hosted in firebase hosting from India, It opens if I use a VPN(set to any other country) since 1 November 2020. **Does anyone know what's the issue??**

firebase support is not convenient for these emergencies, I am losing users in my app.

Comment: Stack Oveflow isn't a support forum.  It's for programming questions.  This is not a programming question.  If you want general discussion, try Reddit.

Comment: It's not firebase problem. same problem i am facing it's issue with Airtel Internet. But i tried with jio internet and it works properly

Comment: *firebaser here* Some providers indeed do seem to be blocking traffic to an IP range used by Firebase Hosting. We're putting a banner on our [status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/), so you can see any progress on it. In the meantime, I recommend reaching out to the hosting providers directly too.

Comment: The problem is limited to Airtel and Act broadband in India. https://twitter.com/labnol/status/1323131738374037505

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Nigeria